# Does a malicious android WebView break the DoubleSubmittCookie countermeasure against CSRF?

Tags: android, web-services, security, csrf

**Initial situation:**

A RESTful webservice defends against CSRF attacks by using the double submit cookie approach. This means that the authentication token gets submitted twice and verified at the service side.

**Problem / Security Threat:**

The WebView element of the android and iOS plattforms allow to create a malicious web browser that unveils and modifies session cookies. **`webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.cookie=’’;");`**. If the attacker already figured out, how the double submitted cookie looks like, (In this case it's the AuthenticationToken) he is able to create a malicious RESTBrowser. Therefore he adds the already known CSRFToken to the document object model and thus bypasses the CSRF countermeasure. Is that right so far?

**Possible Preventions:**

So far I have no idea how I can prevent an attacker from creating und publishing such a malicious mobile application, as well to prevent the service from beeing accessed via malicious mobile applications. I know about the existence of the `User-Agent` header and that the service can use this information to reject requests from others than specific browsers. But I'm sure that also this header can be manipulated within the WebView.

What are effective countermeasures aginst CSRF in contex of malicious mobile applications?

Comment: IMHO, this is not CSRF. This is a malware app ("a malicious web browser"). Hence, this is no different than having "a malicious web browser" on Windows, or OS X, or Linux, or any other platform.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your comment. My point of view is that with mobile apps, the attacker may much easier create and distribute this "Maleware". There may be just a few people who download an install a desktop webbrowser called BookStoreWebClient. In comparison a mobile app called BookStoreMobileClient would for sure be downloaded much more often. This is the reason why I'm so interested in to find another solution to prevent CSRF. Is there no other way?

Comment: IMHO, this is not CSRF. A Web server has no reliable means of determining whether the entity making the HTTP requests is a regular Web browser, "a malicious web browser", or a dog.